# corrupt files after upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have written php script for upload file. It seems to work properly but when open uploaded file in upload folder i get this error:
unknown format or damaged
my code:

HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?=URL?>user/homework" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="csrf" value="<?= $_SESSION['csrf'] ?>" />
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <td><label>file</label></td>
        <td><input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="file"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
            if (Security::chekCsrf($_POST['csrf']) == FALSE) {
                $data = array('', 'dan');
                $this->render('homework', $data);
                exit();
            }
            if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
                $name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 20971520) {
                    $data = array('size high', 'war');
                    $this->render('homework', $data);
                    exit();
                }
                $valid = array('application/octet-stream', 'application/x-rar-compressed', 'application/zip');
                $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                if (!in_array($type, $valid)) {
                    $data = array('wrong format', 'war');
                    $this->render('homework', $data);
                    exit();
                }
                $dir = 'upload/' . $name;
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dir)) {
                    $data = array('ok', 'suc');
                    $this->render('homework', $data);
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $data = array('problem', 'dan');
                    $this->render('homework', $data);
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The upload is done by PHP for you, I doubt there is a bug there. Your usage of `move_uploaded_file` also seems correct. Can you look at the file and see if anything stands out? Is the file empty, or too small, if you open it with a text editor does it look weird?

Comment: yes it werid ,not empty and file size equal primary file

Comment: @RiggsFolly Line 8 of the PHP :)

Comment: You are also not testing the `$_FILES['file']['error']` anywhere. It might be a good idea to check that before assuming the file is successfully uploaded

Comment: @JonStirling I am going blind I need a drink

Comment: You have also told the browser to allow `multiple` file uploads but your code does not actually process/look for multiple files. It might be a good idea to dump the $_FILE to the screen using `print_r($_FILES);` It might actually look a little different to what you are expecting with `multiple` set on the input tag

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Turns out i had two trailing spaces Outside of the  quotations on a php file i use as a handler. Not knowing this can actually corrupt a file on upload. Then this 'unrecognised format' error is given upon attempting to open a downloaded file.